# Daemons fall into what category?

Tags: daemon, architecture

Above system call, there are library routines, utilities and applications. Do daemons fall into any of these categories or they have their own category?

Comment: A daemon is a program waiting for requests to serve. This may be regular action based on time, hardware events user or net input and I bet I forgot lots of possible "inputs" for waking a daemon...

Answer (score 3):

A daemon is just an application. From the Wikipedia article.

> In multitasking computer operating systems, a daemon (/ˈdeɪmən/ or /ˈdiːmən/)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MAC) is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user. Traditionally daemon names end with the letter d: for example, syslogd is the daemon that implements the system logging facility and sshd is a daemon that services incoming SSH connections.

I'll add the history of the term from that same page only because I find it amusing and interesting from a historical perspective.

> The term was coined by the programmers of [MIT's Project MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MAC). They took the name from [Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon), an imaginary being from a famous thought experiment that constantly works in the background, sorting molecules<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#cite_note-2)</sup>. Unix systems inherited this terminology. Maxwell's Demon is consistent with Greek mythology's interpretation of a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28mythology%29) as a supernatural being working in the background, with no particular bias towards good or evil. However, [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) and some of its derivatives have adopted a [Christian daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_art) as their [mascot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_Daemon) rather than a [Greek daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28classical_mythology%29).

#### References

- [Daemon (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)

Comment: Could you answer my another question ["What are considered utilities and applications?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121600/what-are-considered-utilities-and-applications)? It is tightly related to this question.